# SQL Procedure needs to fill in extra columns

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Test EXEC p4_Proc
```

But my table have two extra columns a date with a getdate() datatype and another column that needs to be updated from the application.

Please explain how I can run the query to fill in the date and empty column.

Comment: Modify p4_Proc to insert getdate() and an @argument from the application? Otherwise insert into a temp table/var, update and insert-select or output  into Test.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, so what I did was to insert into the Stored procedure the new column as advised.

Thanks for your help.